# Away 3D tutorials

Tags: actionscript-3, 3d, away3d

Can anyone recommend some good tutorials for Away3D? In particular to create similar effects to those on their home page.
http://away3d.com/

Went to the tutorials page but nothing there...

http://away3d.com/tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would slice up your bitmap into equal squares, and then apply these slices to the front sides of an array of cubes.

Then simply tween the cubes with some random depth, and scale factors.

Answer (score 0):

These aren't tutorials specifically for the effects you're looking for but these helped me get a better understanding of how to use Away3D when I first started playing with it.

http://www.flashmagazine.com/Tutorials/category/away3d/

Unfortunately, I don't recall ever seeing any tutorials specifically for the transition effects you're referencing.